# How to nest loops with iterators?

Tags: javascript, iterator

I have the following code:

```
let array = [0,1,2];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) // j starts at i+1
        console.log(array[i], array[j]);
```

But because of duplicate items, I decided to convert my array to a map. Now I would like to iterate as above on the map:

```
let map = array.reduce(countIntoMap, new Map());
for (let [i,counti] of map.entries())
    for (let [j,countj] of map.entries()) // j starts at 0
        console.log(array[i], array[j]);
```

How could I start looping from `i + 1`?

---

EDIT: here is the function that counts, because I want to know how many occurrences of each element are there.

```
function countIntoMap (map, element) {
    if ( ! map.has(element) )
        map.set(element, 1);
    else
        map.set(element, map.get(element) + 1);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: maps have no addressable order.

Comment: what is countIntoMap

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz. Maps keep the order in which elements were inserted. Can't we take advantage of it? Any alternative structure?

Comment: please add to the edit an example, what you like to achieve. btw, i see no generators here.

Comment: take an array, as given. why map, why genetrators (which do not show up)?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I could use a unique array to loop into, and a map to store duplicate counts, but I hoped to do both in a same structure. It is to count points on a line. You are right, I meant iterators. Same problem with generator though.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

This will create array of `{key, count}` objects and it can be iterated as you wanted

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 2];

const uniq = array.reduce((acc, a) => {

  let idx = acc.findIndex(b => b.key === a);
  idx === -1 ? acc.push({ key: a, count: 1}) : ++acc[idx].count;
  return acc;

}, []);


for (let i = 0; i < uniq.length; ++i) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < uniq.length; ++j) {
    console.log(uniq[i].count, uniq[j].count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe I should use an array and not a map indeed. My question becomes "how to loop a map without converting to array?"